# C# switch comparison

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I'm trying to learn programming C# (self taught) and I came to a point where I don't know if switch case can be used like if condition.

Can I make a comparison with switch like this?

```
switch(var) 
{
    case var < 10:
    //Do something
        break;
}
```

Or this is a case of why if condition is different compared to switch?

Comment: Did you try it to see what happened?

Comment: Yes, it gives me red squiggly lines, and I'm wondering if I understand correctly. if condition is used to compare variables like var < 10 and switch case is just more "strictly" to one option, if that makes sense.

Comment: You can do stuff like that with pattern matching and a `when` clause but if all you need is a single comparison you're better off with an `if`

Comment: Sorry, but what is a pettern matching? EDIT: I've read what is pattern matching. No need to reply to my silly question

Comment: Do not use var. It is reserved keyword.

Comment: @OptionalOption No, it's not.  It's a contextual keyword.  There's a pretty big difference there.

Comment: switch(@switch) works too but is it smart move?

Comment: I see you can also compare variables with switch case, but I think using if condition is more "clear" and shorter compared to swich case, in which you need to use case int value when var < 100: and I found out it is simple using if condition.

Answer (score 0):

Certain comparisons can be done in switch cases via *patterns*. In your specific scenario, a *relational pattern* could check if a switch input is `< 10`.

```cs
switch(var) 
{
    case < 10:
    //Do something
        break;
}
```

One significant limitation of patterns is that the values inside them have to be constant. So if you had a variable `int x` and tried to use it in `case < x:` it wouldn't work.

https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/08/10/relational-pattern-matching-in-c-9/

Comment: case int value when var < 100 for comparning a variable with switch case?

Comment: Yes, a switch case can also have a when clause. So if you need to test against something non-constant you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

Deciding if to use an IF statement or SWITCH statement depends on a number of factors, including the readability of your code.  There are times when multiple IF statements provide a more simpler approach than using switch.  Other times it would be best to use a switch statement.

The simple answer to your question is yes but it would be best for you to try both in a particular scenario if you want to learn.

Comment: I don't know if I'm on the right road, but what I understand is that using switch takes more "characters" to do a simple comparsion compared to a IF condition.

Comment: The saving is when you have lots of conditions chained together. You would not bother with a switch statement with a single condition

Answer (score 0):

For most purposes switch is an alternative way to write an chain of if/else statement

```
switch(myVar) 
{
    case 1:
        //Do something
        break;
    case 2:
        //Do something
        break;
    case 3:
        //Do something
        break;
    default:
        //Do something else
}
```

Is equivalent to

```
if(myVar == 1) {
    //Do something
}
else if(myVar == 2) {
    //Do something
}
else if(myVar == 3) {
    //Do something
}
else {
    //Do something
}
```

In older versions of C# (pre 7.0) case statements were restricted to only testing if values were equal to a constant. However with the introduction of a feature called 'pattern matching' you can do more expressive matches within case statements. Subsequent C# versions have added more and more syntax in this area, but ultimately they don't do anything beyond what can be achieved with an if/else chain. For situations where there are a lot of conditions the switch/case statements are typically easier to read

An example of changes in syntax being allowed C# 9.0

```
switch(myVar) 
{
    case == 1:
        //Do something
        break;
    case > 1 and < 3:
        //Do something
        break;
    case == 3:
        //Do something
        break;
    default:
        //Do something else
}
```

Comment: Switch statement against constants may also translate into different (and faster) machine code, but for almost all modern practical usages it wont make any noticeable difference

Comment: I tried this before ( case > 100 and < 50:) and the IDE gives me a red squiggly line :/

Comment: That syntax only works in C# 9.0 or later. If you're on an earlier version, I think you are stuck using a series of `if` statements.

Comment: The relational patterns can also catch certain kinds of logic errors which can be helpful. 

`switch (x) { case < 10: break; case < 5: break; }`

Here `< 5` gets the "error CS8120: The switch case is unreachable. It has already been handled by a previous case or it is impossible to match."

Comment: @salyonara https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version gives a good overview of what versions are defaulted for which frameworks

Comment: @John Wu I see, so I must check which C# I have

Comment: @Alex, currently my project says I'm using .NET 4.7.2